# Really basic question on copying files between users and machines

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, macos

So I have a MacBook, running macOS Catalina (which is Unix compatible BSD based).

I am buying a new Mac and I want to copy a lot of photos and other bits (like GPG keys, SSH keys, etc) to an external hard-drive, and then when my new machine arrives, copy the files over to the same machine.

Currently files look like this:

`.rw-r--r--      1   312 john staff 13 Dec  2019  gpg.keys`

If I copy this to an external disk with `cp -a` (which is effectively `cp -pPR`), and later to the new MacBook (to the same home folder with the same name, assuming I set up a `john` user on my new Machine), will everything be ok with permissions, or would the two `john` users be 'incompatible' from a permissions perspective.

Maybe I'm over-complicating this, but I want to make sure files have the right permissions...

Maybe one further illustration, if I copy a file with permissions for `John` from a local machine, to an external FAT32 drive, then back to a user `Dave` on a new machine, how does `cp` handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Both John accounts need the same UID. Look for the UID in the old machine (in /etc/passwd 1st field with numbers after john) and then set up the new computer with john and the same UID. Say we found john had uid 1234 on the old computer.
to add the user john with ID 1234 to the new computer

```
useradd -u 1234 -c "John The Ripper" john
```

The other thing you could do so you dont have to match UID's is when the files get to the new computer as root do a recursive chown to get the files owner set to the new john. Then you wont have to match the UID in the two computers.

```
chown -R john:john /path/to/drive/
```

Either method will work and give you the same results.

About your 2nd question. 
When you copy (cp) a file the owner is changed to the user that copied it. 
If you move (mv) a file the attributes and owner stay the same. 
so to answer your question if you copied the file as dave it will have the owner dave. If you move the file it will keep the original owner john.

if you copy files as root then root will own them.

Note the UID is what controls the file ownership. 
to test you can do

```
useradd -u 2345 jimi 
su - jimi from root 
touch /tmp/jimifile 
ls -lah /tmp/jimi* (jimi owns jimifile now)
userdel -r jimi 
ls -lah /tmp/jimi* (will show un-owned jimifile with user id 2345) 
useradd -u 2345 janis 
ls -lah /tmp/jimi* (now will show janis owns jimifile)
```

Comment: ok brilliant thanks! I've had to copy as root as some files weren't copying right without sudo... so on the way back into the new Mac do I simply need to copy as sudo again or should I chown them on arrival? Will permissions be preserved, even if owners change?

Comment: See the piece I added above it explains the ownership of files. 
You may also consider rsync if copying files. this will save attributes and not recopy files that have already been moved. from server1 to local 
    `rsync -avz server1:/var/www   /var/www`